# how to count posts for user add in one month laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to count how many posts the user has added in the current month. I just want to get the number.

This is how I tried but it's not working:

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
$datas = DB::table("posts")
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?' ,[$currentMonth])
    ->get();
```

Comment: created_at >=this month start

Answer (score 1):

You should create a hasMany `posts` relationship in the user model and access it accordingly

Something like this should work

```php
$posts = auth()->user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at',  now()->startOfMonth())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`$startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 months", strtotime(Carbon::now())));
$postCount=Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$startDate,Carbon::now()])->count()`